Как добавить одинаковые теги в элемент canvas, получив на выходe tuple?
При создании тегов через create_text теги создаются как мне надо: одинаковые не удаляются и сохраняются в формате tuple, чтобы я мог к каждому из них потом обратится по индексу.
Далее мне надо удалить все эти теги и добавить новые, где также могут встретиться одинаковые, но tkinter через метод .addtag_withtag уже добавляет только уникальные теги.
Как я понял, нет встроенных средств для замены тегов по индексу.
Я сохранял одинаковые теги путем передачи в addtag_withtag строки с одинаковыми подстроками, но в таком случае в дальнейшем я не смогу обратиться по подстроке к этому элементу.
Мой код:
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
id_txt = canvas.create_text(50, 50, text='Hello', tags=['tx', '0.0', '0.0'])
print(canvas.gettags(id_txt))
for i in canvas.gettags(id_txt):
    canvas.dtag(id_txt, i)
for i in ['tx', '0.0', '0.0']:
    canvas.addtag_withtag(i, id_txt)
print(canvas.gettags(id_txt))
root.mainloop()

Нужен такой ответ после добавления тегов:
('tx', '0.0', '0.0')


А зачем именно вам нужно добавлять несколько одинаковых тегов одному объекту? Это похоже на "ошибку XY"

@insolor Вообщем я получаю данные по вебсокету о цене и объеме(тоже число).Цены я агрегирую и записываю в тэги, они всегда разные. Поэтому нету проблемы. А вот объемы могут быть одинаковые я их тоже должен записать в тэги что бы потом их извлечь, заменить на актуальные и суммировать. Когда приходит цена я получаю ее индекс в кортеже тэгов , и поэтому индексу получаю значение тэга объема что бы его заменить, но если до этого там было два подряд одинакового тэга то по этому индексу может возникнуть исключение indexerror так как одинаковые тэги не добавляются

Не привязывайте эти данные к графическому интерфейсу. Храните в обычных питоновских словарях/списках id объектов и их характеристики.

@insolor я использовал такой подход, но интерфейс начал тормозить, я подумал что  на больших данных выгодней использовать встроенные средства tkinter, чем нагружать данные всякими циклами, пандасами, и списками. Тем более что данные идут постоянно со скоростью 20мс

Наоборот, в первую очередь у вас будет тормозить tkinter от большого количества объектов, а не pandas или даже списки.

@insolor щас еще раз попробовал через словарь но с ключами ввиде Id элементов, кода даже меньше получилось, вроде не лагает пока, спасибо!
